# Retrieving data from database using conditional query concatenation as in SQL query

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a class which is used to carry filtering data. I want to retrieve data from database based on the filtering options. 
My FilteringDto class:

```
public class FilteringDto
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string  search_text { get; set; }

    }
```

I want to retrieve data from `CafeTableGroup` table. This is what my query looks like:

```
 using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession)
                {
                    using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        groups = session.CreateCriteria<CafeTableGroup>().List<CafeTableGroup>();
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filters.search_text))
                        {
                            groups = groups.Where(a => a.field_1.Like(filters.search_text)).ToList();
                        }
                        if (filters.id != 0)
                        {
                            groups = groups.Where(a => a.field_2== filters.id).ToList();
                        }
                        transaction.Commit();

                    }
                }
```

But I have a problem here. In order to get filtered data, first it retrieves all the data in table and then filters it based on the condition. Is there any way that I can do it using a single query and retrieve only the filtered data not all the datas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in your code is `.List<CafeTableGroup>();` which is causing materializing the instances too early. Just delay the call to `List`.

I am not using your exact example. Also, my code uses `IQueryOver` instead of `CreateCriteria`. You can achieve this with code something like below:

```
public IList<Table1Entity> GetList(FilterParams filterParams = null, PageParams pageParams = null)
{
    IList<Table1Entity> instance = null;

    Conjunction conjTable1 = Restrictions.Conjunction();
    Conjunction conjTable2 = Restrictions.Conjunction();

    if(filterParams == null)
        filterParams = new FilterParams();

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterParams.Date))
        conjTable1.Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<Table1Entity>(x => x.Date), filterParams.Date));
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterParams.FromTime))
        conjTable1.Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<Table1Entity>(x => x.FromTime), filterParams.FromTime));
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterParams.ToTime))
        conjTable1.Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<Table1Entity>(x => x.ToTime), filterParams.ToTime));
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterParams.Id))
        conjTable1.Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<Table1Entity>(x => x.Id), Guid.Parse(filterParams.Id)));

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterParams.Pid))
        conjTable2.Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<Table2Entity>(x => x.Pid), Guid.Parse(filterParams.Pid)));

    IQueryOver<Table1Entity> query = NHSession.QueryOver<Table1Entity>()
                .Where(conjTable1)
                .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Table2)
                .And(conjTable2);
    if(pageParams != null)
        query = query.Skip(pageParams.SkipRecords).Take(pageParams.TakeRecords);

    instance = query.List();

    return instance;
}
```

This also demonstrates how to implement joins and paging.

Comment: Sir I didn't understand a thing. Will **NHibernate** retrieve data only after **.ToList()** is called?

Comment: Yes, you are calling `List` too early. Delay the call. Read my sample code carefully. It calls `List` at the end when I am done with adding all my filters.